# Large image not showing dimensions in Media Library

Tags: images, media-library

Why are the dimensions missing in the second screenshot? If I upload a 6MB image, it does not work, but if I upload a smaller 1MB image, the dimensions are showing.

I am using the latest WordPress version.

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this issue in WordPress v4.6. A 15MB image displayed the dimensions 5472 × 3648.

Answer (score 1):

I see this happen when WP runs out of memory or time while processing large images. The image resizing, including setting the attachment custom fields for the dimensions, doesn't complete.  It can be the image dimensions (uncompressed file size really) rather than jpeg file size that are the problem, as the image is decompressed into memory for WP to work on it.

You can try increasing the time that PHP processes can run, if your hosting allows that.

WP has filter hooks just for dealing with this issue and this snippet in my theme's `functions.php` worked for me when I was testing this out.

```
add_filter( 'admin_memory_limit', 'wh_admin_memory_limit' );
add_filter( 'image_memory_limit', 'wh_admin_memory_limit' );

function wh_admin_memory_limit( $limit ) {
    set_time_limit(60);
    return '1024M';

}
```

Setting the longer time limit in this way means you aren't increasing it site wide, so you keep the protection it gives you against runaway processes.

Might be time to get better hosting!